# Find an Element with Selenium/java IEdriver and Click on button to login

Tags: javascript, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

I have been trying to get this element work with selenium/java. This Web app only works in IE9, and written in HTML, Javascript, CSS. please help with sample code.

Code is :

```
form action=/login/main method=get
input type=submit value="Login"
```

[image]

I have tried these methods, but click does not work. I get exception that no such Element.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/form/div/center/table/tbody/tr[4]/td/form/input")).click();
driver.findElement(By.name("submit")).click();
driver.findElement(By.tagName("input")).click();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try first selecting the `form` and from within the `form` select the `input` tag. Try this xpath.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//form[@action='/login/main']/input[@value='Login']")).click();
```

Note that I'm also comparing the value of the attribute of the tags so that the specific required element is selected.

Comment: Your answer is detected as low quality. Add explanation for your code or your answer might permanently be deleted.

Comment: Thanks Jason Estibeiro, your method is working for me.. thank you!